# How to make attributes unique to Gutenberg blocks

Tags: block-editor

I have registered a Gutenberg block using the "registerBlockType" function. Within that function I declare attributes for the block like so:

```
registerBlockType( 'myblock/myblock', {

    attributes: {
        seed: {
            type: 'string'
        },
        compositionData: {
            type: 'string'
        }
    },
    {other wordpress related settings...}
});
```

I then pass the attributes into my edit function, and edit them as such:

```
function Edit( { attributes, setAttributes  } ) {
    setAttributes( { seed: 5 } );
}
```

This all works as expected and attributes.seed is now my random number (assuming I update the post).

The problem however is if I have 2 of "myblocks" on the same post/page, whenever I edit one of them, the other gets edited also. So they will always both share the same seed, and I have no way to differentiate them.

Comment: Do you need a fixed seed that is unique? Or can you just use a random one?

Comment: @kero, This is just an example, really I am saving a large JSON string that I use to configure the block. However the JSON string is currently being shared between all the blocks on the page, and I definitely need this string to be unique and editable for each block.

Comment: Ok, let me ask again to make sure I fully understand: You have some routine to get a default state. This routine should check for other existences of the block on the same page and return unique default states for each block. Right?

Comment: Um no, I thought when I register a block and set attributes for it they all get tied into that specific block. It is in my end to keep track of the attributes? If so what tools do I have available to do that with?

Comment: @kero Also I thought I set the default state of the attribute in the registerBlockType function

Comment: "when I register a block and set attributes for it they all get tied into that specific block" true. And if you set `seed: 5` for each block, each of them will have the same value. You need a custom way to make it unique if you require that. To be honest after your last 2 messages I'm not sure if I fully understand your requirements

Comment: Does "setAttributes( { seed: 5 } );" set the seed to 5 for all blocks? I need a way to create a unique set of values for the attributes I declared in registerBlockType for each block.

Comment: `setAttributes( { seed: 5 } );` sets it for the specific block. However, if you have the same line in each block - it will set the seed to 5 for all blocks. That was why I was talking about a routine to get these values.

Comment: Forgive me I must be confused. How could I not use "the same line" in each block. Doesn't each block use the same edit/save function. Is there something I have to do in these functions to differentiate which block I want to focus on?

Comment: Okay to be clear, I understand that the line above sets the seed to "5" for all blocks, because 5 is hard coded in the line. However if I change "5" to a user input number, all the blocks still update from the last change a user made. So if I make 3 blocks, they all have a unique input, they still will all equal the last change a user made. I can't make them equal different values.

Comment: "How could I not use "the same line" in each block" -> by creating a custom routine that generates the default setting. This routine could read all blocks in the page and make sure to generate a unique set of default values. "However if I change "5" to a user input number, all the blocks still update" -> Either I misunderstand or you've done something wrong. If the `edit` has a input (ie InspectorControls) and you set an attribute via that, only that very specific block should be affected. Just as you can have 2 heading blocks with different levels on a single page.